# Import entire mongodb collection into a Numpy array without looping

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy

I have a mongodb collection consisting of three columns, I just want to read the whole collection into a `m x n` Numpy array, where `m` is the number of records (documents) and `n` is 3. I don't need the keys stored so:

```
my_data = list(collection.find())
```

is not what I am looking for.

The result I want to get is the same that I would get if, instead of a mongodb collection, I had a CSV file and I wrote:

```
my_data = genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: What do your documents look like? Do you have a specific problem with the current implementation?

Comment: then parse the my_data to  whichever type or format you want. Its just a json.

Comment: I know, but can I get what I need in one instruction, without looping, as I can do using genfromtxt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map()` with the cursor object:

```
my_data = list(map(lambda x: list(x.values()), {"_id": False}))

import numpy as np

result = np.array(my_data)
```

Comment: the problem is not filtering the ObjectId (which is anyway something I have to do, you are right) but the fact that I would like to fill the array in without a loop

Comment: You could use `map`: `my_data = list(map(lambda x: list(x.values()), collection.find()))` which returns a list of lists that you can pass to `np.array()`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If you edit the answer adding the final solution, that should be:
my_data = np.array(list(map(lambda x: list(x.values()), collection.find({},{"_id": False}))))
I'll accept it

Comment: Glad to hear it! I changed the answer. But left the code a bit more explicit.